# Spark, efficient way to get a single value from each partitions? accumulator?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, lazy-evaluation, partition, accumulator

In my spark application, each partition generates a single Object, which is small and contains summary of data in the partition. Now i collect them by putting them into the Datafram that also contains main data.

```
val df: DataFrame[(String, Any)] = df.mapPartitions(_ => /*add Summary Object*/ )
val summaries = df.filter(_._1 == "summary").map(_._2).collect()
val data = df.filter(_._1 == "data").map(_._2)  // used to further RDD processing
```

The Summary object is used immediately, and `data` will be used in RDD processing. 
The problem is that, the code yields the evaluation of `df` twice (one in the code, another later on), which is heavy, in my app. And, `cache` or `persist` will help but i cannot use in my app.

Is there any good way to collect the object from each partition? 
How about accumulator?

Comment: Accumulator will not help, since you can't really use accumulated value inside transformations or actions.

Comment: Have you tried `select`

Comment: Why can't you use cache or persist?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin because `df` is could be huge, hundred time bigger than my memory.

Answer (score 1):

Make the function passed to `mapPartitions` return an iterator containing only the summary object. Then you can collect directly, no need of any additional filtering.

Comment: you mean 
```
val summaries = df.mapPartitions(_ => /*add Summary Object*/ ).collect()
val data = df.mapPartitions(_ => /*data process*/)```
 I think it does not solve the problem, because it also requires two evaluations.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't you use cache or persist? – Dennis Jaheruddin
>
> @DennisJaheruddin because df is could be huge, hundred time bigger than my memory. – user2037661

You can use the storage level `MEMORY_AND_DISK` if you want to cache a dataframe that does not fit in memory. This storage level is currently the default one when calling `cache` or `persist`.